# How to define keyframe in media query?

Tags: html, css

Everything works well on displays above 800px, but at or below 800px it does not work as expected.

My HTML and CSS are as follows:

```css
.my_test{
 width:50px;
 height: 50px;
 background:red;
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-animation: aaa 0.5s infinite;
 -o-animation: aaa 0.5s infinite;
 animation: aaa 0.5s infinite;

 position: relative;
}


@-webkit-keyframes aaa {
 from { left:0px; }
 to { left:50px; }
}
@-o-keyframes aaa {
 from { left:0px; }
 to { left:50px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes aaa {
 from { left:0px; }
 to { left:50px; }
}
@keyframes aaa {
 from { left:0px; }
 to { left:50px; }
}

@media screen (max-width: 800px) {
 
 @-webkit-keyframes aaa {
  from { top:0px; }
  to { top:50px; }
 }
 @-o-keyframes aaa {
  from { top:0px; }
  to { top:50px; }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes aaa {
  from { top:0px; }
  to { top:50px; }
 }
 @keyframes aaa {
  from { top:0px; }
  to { top:50px; }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/_test.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="my_test" id="my_test">
  
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Am I using the keyframes incorrectly inside the media query?

Comment: What are you expecting exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply missing the `and` in your media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
```

Here it is working. You can see in the preview pane when you run the snippet, it animates up and down as indicated in the keyframes defined in the media query. To see it working when the width exceeds `800px`, click "full screen."

```css
.my_test{
 width:50px;
 height: 50px;
 background:red;
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-animation: aaa 0.5s infinite;
 -o-animation: aaa 0.5s infinite;
 animation: aaa 0.5s infinite;
 position: relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes aaa {
 from { left:0px; }
 to { left:50px; }
}
@-o-keyframes aaa {
 from { left:0px; }
 to { left:50px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes aaa {
 from { left:0px; }
 to { left:50px; }
}
@keyframes aaa {
 from { left:0px; }
 to { left:50px; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 
 @-webkit-keyframes aaa {
  from { top:0px; }
  to { top:50px; }
 }
 @-o-keyframes aaa {
  from { top:0px; }
  to { top:50px; }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes aaa {
  from { top:0px; }
  to { top:50px; }
 }
 @keyframes aaa {
  from { top:0px; }
  to { top:50px; }
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="my_test"></div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Make sure you accept an answer that solved your problem! :)